# Is $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n - \{(0,0,...,0)\}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, manifolds

In this case, I'm studying manifolds. I had already proved that $\overline B_1(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a n-manifold with boundary, and its boundary is $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, but I have to prove that its boundary is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n - \{(0,0,...,0)\}$ and I'm not sure how to do this. I have this corollary that may help:

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth m-manifold. If $x \in M$, $φ : U\subset H^m \rightarrow W\cap M$
and $Ψ:V\subset H^m →\tilde{W}\cap M$ so that $φ(u_0)=x$ and $Ψ(v_0)=x$, then:
$$
\left(\Psi^{-1} \circ \phi\right): \phi^{-1}(W \cap \tilde{W} \cap M) \rightarrow \Psi^{-1}(W \cap \tilde{W} \cap M) \text { is diffeomorphism }
$$

Comment: Is $\mathbb R^n-0$ compact?

Comment: Also, they don't have the same dimension.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio they do have the same dimension no? $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: How could I use compacty? Could you give me some hint in that part @PedroBrunialti

Comment: this all pretty much looks like a stereographic projection problem

Comment: A diffeomorphism is in particular a homeomorphism, and thus  if two manifolds are diffeomorphic they sahare all topological properties. Also, it is not because a manifold is subset of another that they have the same dimension. The dimension of $S^{n-1}$ is $n-1$ while the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n-0$ is $n$.

Comment: They are homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic.

Comment: @PedroBrunialti You should give an official answer.